# Non-exhaustive patterns in function which is exhaustively defined

Tags: haskell

So i've come across this particular error. Searched the web but didn't find any matches. The weird part is that I can't understand how can it be non-exhaustive.

Here are the functions in cause:

```
myand :: [Bool] -> Bool
myand (x:xs) | null (x:xs) = True
             | null xs = x
             | otherwise = x && myand xs
```

```
myor :: [Bool] -> Bool
myor (x:xs) | null(x:xs) = False
            | null xs = x
            | otherwise = x || myor xs
```

```
safetail :: [a] -> [a]
safetail (x:xs) |null (x:xs) = []
                |otherwise = xs
```

These are very simple functions, defined in files, and all are generating the exception when I try to run them with the empty list.

Example run:

```
*Main> myor [True]
True
*Main> myor []
*** Exception: tp2.hs:(10,1)-(12,38): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myor
*Main> myor [True, False, True]
True
```

Weirdest part is the first two were running fine yesterday - and also generate the same error if "null (x:xs)" is substituted by "length (x:xs) == 0". I also find it interesting that the null (x:xs) = True works for the recursive case but not for the pure empty list case

Comment: No need for the salt - got plenty at home. But thanks for your fast answer :)

Comment: `safetail = drop 1` btw. (Took me some time to figure that out during learning).

Answer (score 7):

Rewriting these to use conditionals instead of guards, we get

```
myand (x:xs) = if null (x:xs) then True
               else if null xs then x
               else x && myand xs

myor (x:xs) = if null(x:xs) then False
              else if null xs then x
              else x || myor xs

safetail (x:xs) = if null (x:xs) then []
                  else xs
```

It is pretty clear that each definition has exactly one clause, with the pattern `x:xs`, and `x:xs` does not match the empty list.
(Note that `null (x:xs)` is never `True`, since `x:xs` is a list with at least one element.)

These are what you intended to match:

```
myand [] = True
myand [x] = x
myand (x:xs)  = x && myand xs

myor [] = False
myor [x] = x
myor (x:xs)  = x || myor xs

safetail [] = []
safetail (_:xs) = xs
```

Also note that `myand` and `myor` only need two clauses.

The reason that your functions don't fail when recursion reaches the empty list is that it doesn't reach it, due to your "exactly one element" guard, `null xs`.

```
myand [] = True
myand (x:xs)  = x && myand xs

myor [] = False
myor (x:xs)  = x || myor xs
```

Comment: Also `myand = all (== True)` and `myor = any (== True)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very apparent in Visual Studio Code / Haskell Language Server:

[image]

The item `(x:xs)` doesn't match `[]`, since `(x:xs)` implies that it has at least one value:

```
matchit (x:xs) = "Match 1"
matchit lst = "Match 2"

-- matchit [] == "Match 2"
-- matchit [1] == "Match 1"
-- matchit [1,2] == "Match 1"
```

Comment: im using VIM for studying this particular language